# how can slice a php code and execute?

Tags: php

my question is that how can slice a php code and execute?
i make a sub url with loop and i want add the sub url to main url.

for example

sub url is : &a=1&b=2&c=3

main url is : http://#site#.com/

actually i want use this way to redirect to some page with header() code !

a code like this...

```
<?php
/////////////////slice 01/////////////////
header("location:
/////////////////slice 01/////////////////

/////////////////slice 02/////////////////
echo $_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER'];
    for($i=0;$i<5;$i++)
        {
            if(!empty($link[$i]))
            {
                echo "&";
                find_link($link[$i]);
            }
        }
/////////////////slice 02/////////////////

/////////////////slice 03/////////////////
");
/////////////////slice 03/////////////////
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I cannot completely understand what you are trying to achieve but  you can use explode  function

```
$subarray = explode("&",$sub_url);
```

this will give you array of values from your sub url.
and after  redirect

```
header("location:".$_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER']."?".implode("&",$subarray));
```

Comment: You surely mean **explode(...)** instead of **extplode(...)**.

Comment: Yes, sorry I misspelled in code. in comment I wrote correctly

Comment: Why explode and implode if you are not doing anything with it?

Comment: What I meant was, if you explode a string and then implode it with the same char, there will be no change. You might as well just use the original string... Take a look at this example: [https://3v4l.org/uK4oW](https://3v4l.org/uK4oW)

Answer (score 0):

I guess what you want to do is that get a part of the url 
www.site.com/page1/&a=1&b=2&c=3

and then combine it with the header location and redirect to that.
www.site.com/page2/&a=1&b=2&c=3

Firstly you need to declare the values in the url
http://#site#.com/page1?a=1&b=2&c=3

Then in php use the following code if you are using object oriented method

```
<?php
//get values from first url    
if (isset($GET['a'], $GET['b'], $GET['c'])){

//store the values in variables
$a = $GET['a'];
$b = $GET['b'];
$c = $GET['c'];

//pass the variables to the function
$yourclassvariable->yourfunctionname($a,$b,$c);

// after function is successful pass values to new url
header("location:www.site.com/page2?a=$a&b=$b&c=$c");
}
?>
```

This should solve your problem